# Vector to data frame using vector's element position as ID number

Tags: r, purrr

Suppose we have a character vector:

```
foo <- c("A;B;C", "B;C", "F;G;H")
```

I wonder how to generate the following data frame:

```
1 A
1 B
1 C
2 B
2 C
3 F
3 G
3 H
```

Please note that numbers in the first column designate position of the component/element in the character vector `foo`.

My initial attempt goes as follows. I use `str_split()` function from `stringr` package to separate elements in the `foo` vector:

```
> str_split(foo, pattern = ";")
[[1]]
[1] "A" "B" "C"

[[2]]
[1] "B" "C"

[[3]]
[1] "F" "G" "H"
```

Now, I guess, the best idea is to use some sort of `map` function from the `purrr` package, but unfortunately I have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

One option is `separate_rows` after creating a `data.frame` with index as the sequence of 'foo'

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(ind = seq_along(foo), Col = foo) %>%
    separate_rows(Col)
```

---

Or using the OP's method, split the 'foo' into a `list`, set the names with the sequence of 'foo' and `stack` to a two column data.frame'

```
stack(setNames(str_split(foo, pattern = ";"), seq_along(foo)))
```

Comment: Thanks, but column numbers does not match desired pattern.

Comment: @Andrej Sorry, fixed it